# JQuery variable: how to convert positive height into negative margin?

Tags: jquery

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var footerheight = $('#footer').height();
        $('#footer').css('height', footerheight);
        $('#footer').css('marginTop', footerheight);
        $('#nonfooterinner').css('paddingBottom', footerheight);
    });
    $(window).bind("resize", function () {
        var footerheight = $('#footer').height();
        $('#footer').css('height', footerheight);
        $('#footer').css('marginTop', footerheight);
        $('#nonfooterinner').css('paddingBottom', footerheight);
    });
</script>

<body>
    <div id="nonfooterouter">
        <div id="nonfooterinner">
            body
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="footer">
        xxx
    </div>
</body>
```

This script grabs the height of the #footer div and sets it as the bottom padding of the inner body wrapper (#nonfooterinner) and the top margin of the #footer. However, the top margin of the #footer needs to be the negative value of that number. How can I convert the variable "footerheight" in the script to a negative number just for the marginTop value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Example on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YHbWD/)

Just set it to negative

```
$('#footer').css('marginTop', - footerheight);
```

Comment: I didn't know you could do that, awesome. Question is now why is always only buggy in IE and nowhere else?

Comment: @user2441996 IE have a bug with "px" or not. If you want to avoid this problem, use `parseInt()`.

Answer (score 3):

```
var footerheight = $('#footer').height();

    $('#footer').css('margin-left', footerheight *-1);
```

Comment: please add some explanation to your solution, showing how it solves the problem and what the questioner was doing wrong or missing.

Comment: This is a great answer Avinash Saini. How does it work?

Answer (score 1):

To convert any value into possitive or vice versa:

```
var value = -500
if(value < 0) { 
  value = value*(-1)
}
```

or to negative:

```
var value = 500
if(value > 0){
  value = value*(-1)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can convert string to int using `parseInt()`. Please check a code below :

```
var footerheight = $("#footer").height();
var marginTop = parseInt(footerheight) * -1;
$("#footer").css("marginTop", marginTop + "px");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var footerheight = $('#footer').height();
footerheight =-Math.abs(footerheight);
```